# How to fix SSL Error in IOS app using HTTPS Host

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cordova, ssl

We have an ios app (built using cordova) which is using our HTTPS Server, in the development environment
we are getting SSL error so we have tried step 1) below and it works.

Workaround

1) Added logic to bypass SSLError in iOS:~ AppDelegate.m

```
@implementation NSURLRequest(DataController)
+(BOOL)allowsAnyHTTPSCertificateForHost:(NSString*)host{
    return YES;
}
@end
```

2) Now we want to submit the app in app store and we saw in various forums that we need to remove the
above Step 1) before submitting the app otherwise it will be Rejected.

We have tried the below codes- A & B in MYAPP-Info.plist in our dev env by removing step 1) from code but it didn't worked.

Code A)

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
 <dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
 </dict>
```

Code B)

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
    <key>OUR_HTTPS_URL</key>
    <dict>
      <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
      <true/>
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
      <true/>
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
      <string>TLSv1.1</string>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

Now the question is~

A) If we just remove the step 1) will the app submission works or it will be failed.?

B) If by removing step 1) app submission failed, what will be the solution to fix this problem so that app will be successfully submitted on app store.?

Thanks,

Comment: Do you use the same server in production and development? You have a problem with certificates, the ones you use aren't trusted by ios devices.

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 apps that bypass this using info.plist.  There was no issue getting them approved.  I use these on my dev setup and on production I use an HTTPS connection. Here is the entry from my info.plist.  Notice that I have 2 domains that have exceptions.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>YOUR FIRST DOMAIN GOES HERE</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
        <key>YOUR SECOND DOMAIN GOES HERE</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

So I can say for sure that you can have domain exceptions and still get approved.

Comment: We tried using plist file but it didn't worked, if we add the domain specific check in code will it work?

Comment: You are using cordova and I have no idea what that does. In Xcode, the plist file is named "info.plist" not "MYAPP-Info.plist".

Comment: thanks, can you let me know the exact location of this plist file in xode?